# reactjs: usestate with object, values not getting changed

Tags: reactjs

I have

```
function randomNum(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

  var default_variables = {
                        a: randomNum(2,9),
                        b: randomNum(1,9),
                        c: randomNum(2,9)
                      }
  const [variables,setVariables] = useState(default_variables)

  function refreshVariables(){
    setVariables({ ...variables,
                  a: randomNum(2,9),
                  b: randomNum(1,9),
                  c: randomNum(2,9)
                })
  }
```

and

```
                <Button 
                  variant="contained" 
                  color="primary"
                  onClick= {refreshVariables}
                  >
                  Refresh
                </Button>
                <div>{variables.a},{variables.b},{variables.c}</div>
```

I can see the state in the chrome devtools keep changing when i refresh, but the components are not rerendering with the changed values

I even tried

```
    setVariables(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      a: randomNum(2,9),
      b: randomNum(1,9),
      c: randomNum(2,9)
    }));
```

Comment: can you please add implementation of `randomNum` function?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hodgkin-5opov?file=/src/App.js
I think it works

Comment: It's working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/random-number-kul6f

Comment: yes, the code i working in codesandbox

Comment: I have to check, but no clue

Comment: I found the problem is with react-mathquill. I am using actually `<StaticMathField>{variables.a}({variables.b}x+{variables.c})</StaticMathField>`. its not updating

Answer (score 0):

try removing "...variables",

another thing to try is write

```
 onClick= {()=>{refreshVariables}}
```

instead of

`onClick= {refreshVariables}`